# Sorting a List of Locations

Tags: java, android, sorting

I want to sort a list of `android.location.Location`. The sort should base on the distance of my location to the location from the list. So i think the distance should be calculated during the search process. And so I've decided to use insert sort.

Is this the right choice?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's a `List` of locations, I'd go with `Collections.sort` + a custom `Comparator`:

```
final Location myLocation = someLocation;

Collections.sort(locations, new Comparator<Location>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Location o1, Location o2) {
        Float dist1 = o1.distanceTo(myLocation);
        Float dist2 = o2.distanceTo(myLocation);
        return dist1.compareTo(dist2);
    }
});
```

Comment: to you think it would be faster than my solution?

Comment: Let me answer that with a counter-question: Do you think you're a better programmer than the developers of the Java collections framework at Sun/Oracle?

Comment: i don't think so :) but i think with my solution i will fewer call the .distancTo()-method

Comment: heheh.. smells like micro-optimizations to me. But if it's a concern, you could pair up the locations + distances in one pass, and then do Collections.sort on the list of pairs (based on the distance-parts).

Comment: sorry...but i don't understand exectly how you mean that. Can you explain it pleace

Comment: If you really want to keep the number of calls to `distanceTo` at a minimum (you shouldn't care about it until you have identified it as a bottle neck in your application though!) you can do the following: Based on your list of locations, create a list of pairs (location, distance). Let the comparator sort this list based on the distance component. Extract the sorted list of locations from the list of (sorted) pairs.

Comment: Collections.sort uses a version of Merge Sort where they use the 'divide and conquer' methodology to divide the list, then use insertion sort to sort the divided atomic lists, then merge them back together and repeat until the sort is complete. which is on average a time complexity of O(n*log(n)) but since they use insertion sort for the atomic sorts the worse case for that is O(n^2) but it is pretty unlikely that the atomic lists would be in reverse order and usually these sub lists are much smaller anyway so it shouldn't impact the performance too heavily.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of locations in your list, you may want to think about the time complexity of the sorting algorithm.

Insertion Sort has the Worst Case Senario time complexity of O(n^2) [n is the number of items in the list] meaning if the list to sort was a reversed sorted list it would have to traverse through the entire list for every object in the list in order to sort it. This may not seem like a problem unless you have very large lists.

if you aren't going to be having extremely large lists to sort through, insertion sort can work fine for your situation. Some other sorts you could look into include Selection Sort, Bubble Sort, Quick Sort or Merge Sort.